# iterating objects in a list through a loop

Tags: python

So I'm just doing a learning project and I need some help.

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self):
        self.speed = 0
        self.color = ""
        self.weight = 0
        self.engine = 4
        self.name = ""
        self.mpg = 25
        self.maintenanceLog = []
        self.oilChanges = []
        
    #mutator methods
    
    def setSpeed(self, sp):
        self.speed = sp
        
    def setColor(self, cl):
        self.color = cl
    
    def setWeight(self, w):
        self.weight = w
        
    def setEngine(self, e):
        self.engine = e
    
    def setName(self, n):
        self.name = n
    
    def setMpg(self, mpg):
        self.mpg = mpg
        
    def addOilChange(self, oc):
        self.oilChanges.append(oc)
    
    def addMaintenance(self, ml):
        self.maintenanceLog.append(ml)
    
    #accessor methods    
    def getSpeed(self):
        return self.speed
    
    def getColor(self):
        return self.color
    
    def getWeight(self):
        return self.weight
        
    def getEngine(self):
        return self.engine
    
    def getName(self):
        return self.name
        
    def getMPG(self):
        return self.mpg
        
    def getAllOilChanges(self):
        print("")
        print("----------OIL CHANGES----------")
        for oc in self.oilChanges:
            print(oc)
    
    def getMaintenanceLogs(self):
        print("")
        print("----------MAINTENANCE LOGS----------")
        for ml in self.maintenanceLog:
            print(ml)
        
        
def setInfo(car):
    car.setSpeed(int(input(f"Speed of {car}")))
    car.setWeight(int(input(f"Weight of {car}")))
    car.setName(input(f"Name of {car}"))
    car.setColor(input(f"Color of {car}"))
    car.setEngine(int(input(f"Engine of {car}")))
    car.setMpg(int(input(f"Miles per Gallon of {car}")))

def getInfo(car):
    print(f"Speed of {car} is {car.getSpeed()} mph.")
    print(f"Weight of {car} is {car.getWeight()} pounds.")
    print(f"Name of {car} is {car.getName()}.")
    print(f"Color of {car} is {car.getColor()}.")
    print(f"Engine cylinders of {car} are {car.getEngine()}.")
    print(f"Miles per Gallon of {car} is {car.getMPG()}.")

def main(): 
    carList = []
    Object1= Car()
    
    carList.append(Object1)
    print(carList)
    for obj in carList:
        setInfo(obj)
        getInfo(obj)
        
main()
```

Thats's the code, now, whenever I run it, I want to get asked Speed of Object1:

Instead, I get asked Speed of <**main**.Car object at 0x0000024B093CEFD0>:

How can I see the name of the object instead of that hash value... I want to keep adding objects with the class Car and then pass them through a loop to fill in the information regarding the object, but if the list of objects was [Object 1, Object 2, Object 3... Object N] I want it to refer to that name (Object 1) instead of <**main**.Car object at 0x0000024B093CEFD0>

Comment: Use `f"Speed of {car.name}"`

Comment: I tried that but now I see Speed of

nothing else

Comment: That's because you set the name to an empty string when you created the car. What name do you expect to see?

Comment: i want to set it myself, because there will be more than one car.... I just want it to ask me the name of the object when prompted about the speed, rather than the hash value

Comment: Note that what you see is **not** the hash value of the name of the variable containing your object (which is not even intrinsic to the object, because there could be aliasing) but its id, which is CPython corresponds its memory location.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the name to use in the prompts as an argument to `setInfo()`.

```
def setInfo(car, name=None):
    if name is None:
        name = car.name
    car.setSpeed(int(input(f"Speed of {name}")))
    car.setWeight(int(input(f"Weight of {name}")))
    car.setName(input(f"Name of {name}"))
    car.setColor(input(f"Color of {name}"))
    car.setEngine(int(input(f"Engine of {name}")))
    car.setMpg(int(input(f"Miles per Gallon of {name}")))
```

and then use that in the loop.

```
for i, obj in enumerate(carList, 1):
    setInfo(obj, f"Object {i}")
    getInfo(obj)
```

Comment: what if I want to change the objects name to like Lightning, Sally, Doc

Instead of Object 1, 2, 3, 4 etc

Comment: Where do those names come from? How does the loop know what the names should be?'

Comment: i would create something like this under main

Lightning = Car()
Sally = Car()
Doc = Car()

carList.append(Sally)
carList.append(Lightning)
carList.append(Doc)

Comment: That's not possible. The list just contains the objects, there's no link to the original variable names.

Comment: You could use a dictionary that maps names to objects. Then you can pass the dictionary key to `setInfo`.

Comment: But if the name is in the variable, why do you also have `self.name`?

Comment: I see, yeah I can just use Objectn as a object name and call it a day... thanks for the help!

Comment: Let's say I want to now getInfo on a car, and the user inputs the name of the car, what is the correct syntax

Comment: Search your list for the car whose name matches what they entered. Or use a dictionary.